# Unique id attributes needed for second form on page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that separates the date from a datepicker into day, month, and year. It works fine when there is one form on the page but not when there is a second one (presumably due to the id being the same). How can I add a value to my id and name so that they are unique values?

```
var now = new Date();
var date = jQuery('.form-date');
var day = ("0" + now.getDate()).slice(-2);
var month = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
var today = now.getFullYear()+"-"+(month)+"-"+(day) ;

date.val(today);

jQuery('form').on('submit', function() {


    var newVal = date.val().split('-'), 
        dateParts = {
            year: parseInt(newVal[0], 10),
            month: parseInt(newVal[1], 10),
            day: parseInt(newVal[2], 10)
        };

    jQuery('.anchor').append(jQuery.map(dateParts, function (index, key) {
        var name = 'date_' + key;

        return jQuery('<input>', {
            type: 'hidden',
            name: name,
            id: name,
            value: dateParts[key]
        });
    }));

});
```

Comment: IDs should be unique, no matter what.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that my code is not creating a unique id.

Answer (score 0):

Need declare a variable that determines the current form:

```
(function ($) {
    var now = new Date();
    var date = $('.form-date');
    var day = ("0" + now.getDate()).slice(-2);
    var month = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    var today = now.getFullYear() + "-" + (month) + "-" + (day);

    date.val(today);

    var form = $('form.reservation');

    form.on('submit', function () {
        var currentForm = $(this);
        var newVal = currentForm.find('.form-date').val().split('-'),

            dateParts = {
                year: parseInt(newVal[0], 10),
                month: parseInt(newVal[1], 10),
                day: parseInt(newVal[2], 10)
            };

        currentForm.find('.anchor').append($.map(dateParts, function (index, key) {
            console.log(['date', form.index(currentForm), key].join('_'));
            return $('<input>', {
                type: 'hidden',
                name: ['date', key].join('_'),
                id: ['date', form.index(currentForm), key].join('_'),
                value: dateParts[key]
            });
        }));

    });
})(jQuery);
```